# Why my custom URIs work in browser's bar but not in PDF links?

Tags: pdf, browser, deep-linking

I am creating an application that needs to open pdf documents from some custom URI written inside some other pdf documents.

So it's like: "Custom URI in pdf" -> MyApp -> "Another pdf Document".

If my custom URI is: myapp://somePage and I enter it in my Chrome Browser's address bar, it works! :D

But if I input the URI in a pdf link, it doesn't... :(

Could someone, whom I would be very grateful to, explain to me why this happens? What are the differences between a link in my browser's address bar and a link in a pdf document?

The application currently runs and works on Android, with this feature, however, no way to make it work on windows 10... I decide to ask this very question in case it would help me to understand a bit more what happens during the process, so this is the reason why I don't give more info about the app. :)

Thanks in advance for all the help you may bring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Acrobat Reader DC, that I was using, doesn't allow custom protocol URI, for security reasons.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1275025